# Im trying to update an item on BlockBreakEvent but it doesnt update correctly

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Im updating an item on BlockBreakEvent, it updates the NBT tags but it doesnt update lore, this is my code:

```
List<String> lore = new ArrayList<>();
                lore.add("§7Level: §b" + level);
                lore.add("§7XP: §9 " + xp + "/" + xpreq);
                pickaxeMeta.setLore(lore);
                
                pickaxe.setItemMeta(pickaxeMeta);
                itemCompound.setInt("level", level);
                itemCompound.setInt("xp", xp);
                itemCompound.setInt("xpreq", xpreq);
                nmsItem = CraftItemStack.asNMSCopy(pickaxe);
                nmsItem.setTag(itemCompound);
                pickaxe = CraftItemStack.asBukkitCopy(nmsItem);
                player.getInventory().setItem(player.getInventory().getHeldItemSlot(), pickaxe);
                player.updateInventory();
```

Anything Im missing why the lore isnt updating? There are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you set the tag to a compound that does not include the lore.

You can get the tag after setting the item meta using `nmsItem.getTag()`.

Comment: Could you edit the question with your attempts?